# Laravel Posts that have specific tags and except have specific tags

Tags: laravel, database, eloquent, tags

i have 2 model => **post** and **tag** (many to many relation), also tag has 2 type like "trending" and "restrict"

*tag model table* : id - tag_type - tag_title - tag_slug

```
public function getTags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class, 'tags_posts', 'post_id', 'tag_id');
}
```

i need to get posts that : when $request->trending exist return posts that have tag_type == "trending" and tag_title == $request->trending **Also** (*this isn't conditionally and always check*) except posts that have tag_type == "restrict" and tag_slug == "simple2"

i need eloquent laravel not php database , and it's important to be optimize

thanks a millions

Comment: side note: the relationship method should be named `tags` and the pivot would be `post_tag` to follow convention; then you would only need 1 argument to `belongsToMany`

Comment: thanks, names not problem and they work

Comment: what does this mean: "when `$trending="simple"` exist" ? where does that variable come from?

Comment: @lagbox - yes it's variable and get from request  :  $trending = $request->trending;

Comment: sounds like you are looking for `whereHas` and `whereDoesntHave` ... its in the Eloquent Relationship docs, Querying Relationship Existence/Absence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on lagbox's comment, you're looking for whereHas and whereDoesntHave, passing a closure to each to do your filtering:

```
Post::whereHas('tags', function($q) use($request){
    if ($request->trending) {
        $q->where('tag_type', $request->trending);
    }       
})
->whereDoesntHave('tags', function($q){
    $q->where([
        'tag_type' => 'restrict',
        'tag_slug' => 'simple2'
    ]);
});
```

WhereHas will select only posts that have a tag with tag_type === $request->trending,
WhereDoesntHave will filter out posts that have a tag with tag_type === 'restricted' and tag_slug === 'simple2'.